# How can this related to the Dirichlet 's Kernel

Tags: analysis, fourier-analysis, fourier-series

The problem is that:

> Show that for all $a \in \mathbb{R}$,
> $$|\sin(ax)\sin\left((a+\tfrac12)x\right)|\geq |\sin^2(ax)\cos(\tfrac{x}{2})|-|\sin(\tfrac{x}{2})|.$$

My idea is through simple calculation to show that $\sin(ax)\sin\left((a+\tfrac{1}{2})x\right) = \sin^2(ax)\cos(\tfrac{x}{2}) - \sin(\tfrac{x}{2})$ which I failed at,
$\sin(ax)\sin\left((a+\frac{1}{2})x\right) = \cos(\frac{x}{2})(1-\sin^2(ax))-\cos(ax)\sin(ax)\sin(\frac{x}{2}).$
The hint from the problem(a) is that $\frac{1}{2} + \sum_{n=1}^{N}\cos(nx)= \pi D_N(x)$, and the general formula for $D_N(x)$, but I don't know how to use it. Thanks!

Comment: Let $a=0$ and $x=\pi$, then
$$\sin(ax)\sin\left((a+\tfrac12)x\right)=\sin(0\pi)\sin(\tfrac12\pi)=(0)(1)=0$$
$$\sin^2(ax)\cos(\tfrac{x}{2})=\sin^2(0\pi)\cos(\tfrac{\pi}2)=(0)(0)=0$$
$$\sin(\tfrac{x}{2})=\sin(\tfrac{\pi}2)=1$$
hence the inequality does not hold.

Comment: Yes, you are right. So is there any way to use $D_N(x)$?